# braking up multiclass classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-encoding

I am working on a data set that has tabled data to 5 different classes. I would like to train an algorithm (logreg most likely) to predict cluster affiliation. but because there are 5 classes all the algorithms I have tested performed very poorly.
I was wondering is there a reason not to one-hot encode my target, and then train 5 different algorithm for each unique label?

Thank you

Comment: Although it's possible, I wouldn't generally recommend it. The issue with fitting a separate model for each class is that it ignores an important feature of the problem--that classes are mutually exclusive. It might be useful in certain, limited circumstances (e.g. where you truly care about membership in a particular class vs. all others)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at one-vs-one and one-vs-all ensemble leaners. For example, you can use an ensemble of logistic regression models. You could also explore support vector machines too.

Your idea about one-hot encoding the classes isn't a bad idea. After the one-hot encoding you could instead consider [multinomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) rather than 5 distinct models. This assumes you can't have more than one class 'activated' at a time (mutually exclusive), so the probabilities assigned from the multinomial regression will sum to 1.

Comment: Multinomial logistic regression gives a categorical distribution over multiple, mutually exclusive class labels. The OP asked about fitting separate logistic regression models, giving separate Bernoulli distributions representing membership in each class. This doesn't enforce the constraint that classes are mutually exclusive (class membership probabilities don't sum to. one), so it's distinct from multinomial logistic regression. Rather, it's a form of multilabel classification.

Comment: Sure - but I mean the idea of performing a one hot encoding and then classing over those mutually exclusive labels is like multinomial regression. Didn't mean that they were apples to apples - but can see why it might be confusing. Will edit answer.